# how to give line space in string of object property in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to give the line space between strings of the content property. How Can I give it?. Like after World Wide Web string I want to start a new string from a new line. Look at my code here
Note: I am using this in React Native Application

```
const data = [
  {
    title: 'What is Html',
    content:
      'HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the basic building block of World Wide Web.',
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using backticks `` instead of "" . that will solve your problem . Like

```
content: `HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language
HTML is the basic building block of World Wide Web.
`
```

See a working example [snack](https://snack.expo.io/S13jWVGCH) .

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts.